# Dynamic CRM Online import data maintaining records ownership

Tags: dynamics-crm, data-migration, dynamics-crm-online

I have a task to migrate Data from a CRM on premise data to a CRM online organization. I used two options, which are, migrated data using CRM import wizard and [MSCRM Toolkit](http://mscrmtoolkit.codeplex.com/). But in both options, ownership of the records change to the user who migrated the data and the created on date is also got changed.

In my application, owners of the records are important because some of the filtered views are based on that information. Hence is there a better way(tool or process) to migrate the data maintaining the record ownership?

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest to use [SSIS Integration Toolkit from Kingswaysoft](http://www.kingswaysoft.com/products/ssis-integration-toolkit-for-microsoft-dynamics-crm). Inside it you can map owners between old and new CRM. Also you can use overriddencreatedon field during import to override creation date of a record with actual value.

Comment: Using a free licence of SSIS Integration Toolkit from Kingswaysoft, can I transport data from on premise CRM to Online CRM?